# Android database location in app directory

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite

I don't understand why database files are stored in the android emulator or phone in the data folder data/data//databases rather than being stored in the application that uses it.

Logically, the database file must also be stored in the android app, right ?

If yes, where should it be stored in the app directory ?

Comment: Where should the database file be in the app directory of an Android project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your database in your assets folder, then its path is given by `"/data/data/<your-package-name>/databases/<dbname>"`

Comment: Where is the asset folder. I can't find it

Comment: Is it <my-app-name>/build/assets ?

Comment: are you using any IDE, android studio, or eclipse?

Comment: I was using Eclipse, but I have switched to Android Studio, because apparantly, it is better for Android apps

Answer (score 1):

your database will be saved under `data/data/myApp/database` and not in any other folder but your application folder,  since database consider as a private to your app, android make it hard for people with non-root access to see your database. you still can store it in any place you like just point to it from your app.